# Split string based on multiple words

Tags: javascript

Given the string below, how can I split it and join it with a "&" based on certain words?

```
search?commute[]=under2salary[]=under75role[]=sales
```

The proper format should be:

```
search?commute[]=under2&salary[]=under75&role[]=sales
```

Basically, I just want to add a "&" before each new word, in this case "role" and "salary". "Commute" should not have a "&" before it since it is the first word in the string.

Comment: Consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams instead of manual string manipulations.

Comment: Is it always these same words? Should the `&` always follow a number, like in your example?

Comment: @YuriyYakym it looks like they want to _preprocess_ the string because it's malformed, before it makes sense as URLSearchParams input.

Comment: @RogerFedFan where is this string coming from? Because no HTML form, nor Fetch-based request, will generate bad query argument strings like that. Rather than fixing the result, the proper fix here would be to fix the _source_ so that that doesn't generate bad strings anymore.

Comment: If it's always the same words, i would do a .replace and replace under75 with under75&, etc

Comment: There are a couple of words but the main idea is to have a "&" before salary and role

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this code, It splits the array based on certain words and joins with '&'

```
let str = 'search?commute[]=under2salary[]=under75role[]=sales';
let splitArr = ['salary', 'role'];
splitArr.forEach(item => {
  str = str.split(item).join('&' + item);
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: `under2` and `under75` were just for an example. It is very likely there will be any other number

Comment: @YuriyYakym - Question was 'Split string based on multiple words' - So can't we add any number of words in splitArr to get the result.

Comment: `under2` and `under75` are not words

Comment: Then what are those?

Comment: Word is a sequence of letters, not letters and digits

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really cannot fix source of the problematic query string, I think you can replace `=\word\number\word` with `=\word\number&\word`.
Consider this code:

```js
function fixUrl(url) {
  return url.replace(/(=\w+\d+)(\w+)/g, (_, group1, group2) => `${group1}&${group2}`);
}

const url = `search?commute[]=under2salary[]=under75role[]=sales`;
const fixedUrl = fixUrl(url);

console.log(fixedUrl);
```